# Java Mockito when() passing in multiple parameters, including a Builder

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing a unit test that calls another method with three parameters

```
 Mockito.when(myclass.method(value1, value2, myOtherClass.Builder)).thenReturn(myObject)
```

I cannot pass in

```
when(myclass.method(value1, value2, any(myOtherClass.Builder.class))...
```

for the third parameter because of the mismatch between real values and any() arguments as a restriction of Mockito. I also cannot pass in a new Builder because it won't be the same Builder that gets passed in once the method is called.

How can I test that the exact values of the first two parameters are passed in, plus that the correct builder is passed in?

Comment: Please, show the actual signature of the mocked method. Is there a builder or an actual built object parameter accepted there?